# How can I fix a MySQL Error for mysql shell for vs code

Tags: mysql, database, shell, localhost

I installed the MySQL shell for VS code extension but whenever I try to open a database I created I get an error.

The error reads:

> Error:Shell.open_session: Access denied for user...

[image: Image of the error]

I tried creating new databases some with passwords some without but same result.

Comment: install mysql workbench and try to login with the user

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?